# Validation rule on user input

Tags: validation, account, regular-expressions

I'm trying to restrict users of filling in certain values in a VAT field. I want them to follow the VAT convention PREFIX-NUMBER(ex. BE0121569515)

I made a validation rule to restrict on character length and that one works.

My rule to restrict special characters is as follows:

```
NOT(REGEX(  VAT__c , "^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$"))
```

This used to work and would restrict users filling in special characters. but lately this validation rule has stopped working and I can't get it working anymore.

Has anyone else encountered the issue where validation rules stop working all of a sudden and how could I configure this rule to get my desired outcome?

Comment: Did you check that it is still active?

Comment: fair remark, but unfortunately the rule is active

Comment: Would this work for you?
`[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{10}`

Comment: Did it stop working when Spring '22 was deployed in your org, or did that not coincide? If it was coincidental, you might want to check the Spring '22 release notes for anything to do with validation rules, formulae and/or REGEX. (I haven't looked so I don't know - I'm just spitballing.)